# "Command not found: complete" message appears every time I open the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zsh, ubuntu-20.04

I was setting up my development environment on Ubuntu 20.04 following a video on Youtube and after running the command

$ echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.zshrc

Every time I open the terminal the message appears:

/home/gustavo/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash:80: command not found: complete

Does anyone know what I could have done wrong and how can I fix it?

Just to point out, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Look at asdf.bash and remove the offending statement. Otherwise edit .zshrc and remove the script so it no longer starts.

Comment: Post the relevant section of `asdf.bash` that contains `~/.zshrc` you should provide 5-10 lines at most.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 8):

If you are mac user using **.zsh**

just add the following to your **.zshrc** file

```
autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
```

for more info refer to link : https://github.com/eddiezane/lunchy/issues/57

duplicate answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73575734/1283215

Comment: thank you, this is a life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

What that error means is that a command that you used in asdaf.bash is apparently no longer on your computer. To try and remedy the situation:

- **Is `complete` actually installed?** Try using `apt show complete` to see if it's installed. If it is, `[installed]` should be at the end of the line.
- **Is `complete` another script?** If so, use this syntax (assuming complete is in your home directory)

```
~/./complete
```

- **Is the surrounding code correct?** I've found a syntax error in the surrounding code sometimes makes a big difference in this command, especially if it involves piping or new lines.

Hope this helps,

Mac Henni

Comment: `complete` is not a package (which could be checked with apt) or even a program (_some_ programs have the same name as their package but many do not); it is a _builtin_ feature of bash but not in zsh which OP appears to be using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

I used de  `apt show complete` and looked for the COMPLETE command and it does not exist and is not installed.

But I found the file asdf.bash in /home/gustavo/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash and removed the offending statement. This made the message stop appearing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).